# Difference between ctrl+e and ctrl+k in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

How <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> is different from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> in Chrome?

I could not find any difference between these two keyboard shortcuts in google-chrome, both navigates to search bar with 'Search Google' enabled. Isn't there any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According Google Chrome help (see https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179) both keyboard shortcuts are for the same command.